# Key-Value pairs by List generator from an OrderedDict from an OrderedDict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, listiterator

I want to make a list generator from a large list/OrderedDict arranged like the one below:

```
x = OrderedDict([
    (u'attributes',
        OrderedDict([(u'type', u'Lead'),
                     (u'url', u'sobjects/Lead/BWEAZ')])),
    (u'ConvertedAccountId', u'001i000000eA7K3AAK'),
    (u'Company', u'Farmers Coop. of Florida'),
    (u'ConvertedAccount',
        OrderedDict([(u'attributes',
                          OrderedDict([(u'url', None)])),
                     (u'CreatedDate',
                          u'2014-02-26T23:52:13.000+0000')])),
    (u'CreatedDate', u'2014-02-01T17:36:41.000+0000'),
    (u'LN_SCORE__c', None)]
)
```

I get part of what I want by:

```
gb = [{k: v for k, v in d.iteritems() if k == 'ConvertedAccountId' or
                                         k == 'Company' or
                                         k == 'CreatedDate' or
                                         k == 'LN_Score__c'} for d in x]
```

but I don't know how to include the 'CreatedDate' for 'ConvertedAccount' since the value for 'ConvertedAccount' is another OrderedDict and 'CreatedDate' is a key.

Whatever the solution I will have to rename 'CreatedDate' since there is another key in the outer dict with the same name. Don't care about order.

Comment: I find that when you start having to scroll sideways while reading a list comprehension or a generator expression, you should convert to a loop.

Comment: A number of values in `x` aren't `OrderedDict`s, yet your comprehension tries to call `iteritems()` on all of them (and fails on the ones that aren't). What exactly to you want to end up in `gb`?

Comment: I'm not sure if the repeated "from an OrderedDict" in your title is a typo, so I haven't edited it.

Comment: I want to get key value pairs of (u'ConvertedAccountId', u'001i000000eA7K3AAK'), (u'Company', u'Farmers Coop. of Florida'), and (converted account created date, 2014-02-26T23:52:13.000+0000')
But the problem is the label 'Created date' is shows up twice(one is for account the other is for lead) and the date is in a dict within a dict.

Comment: goal is to get:
gb=[(u'ConvertedAccountId', u'001i000000eA7K3AAK'), (u'Company', u'Farmers Coop. of Florida'),(u'CreatedDate', u'2014-02-01T17:36:41.000+0000'),(u'LN_SCORE__c', None),(AccountCreatedDate,'2014-02-26T23:52:13.000+0000')]